# Outputting 20 different random numbers within a range using php

Tags: php, arrays, random

I've created this code to output 20 random numbers from 5 to 100 in PHP. All the numbers must be different from each other.
While executing I'm taking this error

[image]

This is my code:

```
<?php  

$a=array();
while(count($a)<20){
$found=false;
$random=rand(6,100);
for($i=0;$i<=count($a);$i++){
    if($a[$i]==$random){
        $found==true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!$found)
    $a[count($a)]=$random;


}
echo $a;

?>
```

Can someone help me to deal with this error? Thanks!

Comment: There are much easier ways to fo this. Range () and shuffle come to mind

Comment: You have to rethink this code or you will get ALOT of notices along the way. Also you cant echo an array `echo $a` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple code

```
<?php  
$a=array();
while(count($a)<20){
   $random=rand(6,100);
   if(!in_array($random, $a)){
      $a[] = $random;
   }

}
print_r($a);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution :

```
$a = array();
$j = 0;
while ($j < 20) {
    $random = rand(6, 100);
    if (!in_array($random, $a)) {
        $a[] = $random;
        $j++;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($a);
```